# Heroku site is right, local is wrong. How can clone my heroku code locally?

Tags: javascript, css, git, heroku, localhost

I created a static site using just css and javascript. Everything seems to be working on Heroku, with the same code that is locally, but for some reason when I run the site locally the css has a lot of problems. Has anyone had this issue before and could provide some insight? Or is there a way to clone the code from heroku back to my local repository? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it isn't finding the CSS file due to paths. Have you confirmed it is using some styles from it in the local set up? If it isn't that, then please show your Html and CSS code, and specify what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the existing heroku app to your local machine heroku git:clone -a myapp to [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app)

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

> To clone the source of an existing application from Heroku using Git,
> use the heroku git:clone command: Replace myapp with the name of your
> app.
>
> This will create a new directory named after your app with its
> source and complete repository history, as well as adding a heroku git
> remote to facilitate further updates.

But as mentioned in comments, the problem might be mainly because css file paths , so if this doesn't fix it  make sure sure all the css files are being linked correctly using the **browser developer tools** .

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for, and worked perfectly.